# data.table: cartesian join and nomatch

Tags: r, data.table

I want to do a cartesian (full outer) join using the fabulous data.table package in R. However, I want unmatched rows to be mentioned as well, i.e. my two data.tables "left" and "right" look like

```
key | data_left
  1 |       aaa
  2 |       bbb
  3 |       ccc
```

and

```
key | data_right
  1 |        xxx
  2 |        yyy
```

The cross join with a key column "key" gives me

```
key | data_left | data_right
  1 |       aaa |        xxx
  2 |       bbb |        yyy
```

however, the unmatched row `3 | ccc` is completely missing. Adding the option `nomatch=0` (instead of `nomatch=NA`) did not help. I want data.table to just fill up the remaining columns with NA so I expect

```
key | data_left | data_right
  1 |       aaa |        xxx
  2 |       bbb |        yyy
  3 |       ccc |         NA
```

**Any idea what I can do in order to get this to work?**

Code sample:

```
library(data.table)
left = data.table(keyCol = c(1,2,3), data_left = c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"))
right = data.table(keyCol = c(1,2), data_right = c("xxx", "yyy"))
setkey(left, keyCol)
setkey(right, keyCol)
res0 = left[right, allow.cartesian=TRUE, nomatch=NA]
resNA = left[right, allow.cartesian=TRUE, nomatch=0]
```

Comment: Isn't this working?  `merge(left, right, by="key", all=T)`

Comment: @Prem: This seems to do the job, thanks!

Comment: @HongOoi ah no? If I understand correctly then w3schools thinks it is: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp...

Comment: Oops, misread the code sample

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is at most one row per `keyCol` value, I'd do...

```
# setup
kc = "keyCol"
DTs = list(left, right)

# make main table with key col(s)
DT = unique(rbindlist(lapply(DTs, `[`, j = ..kc)))

# get non-key cols
for (d in DTs){
  cols = setdiff(names(d), kc)
  DT[d, on=kc, (cols) := mget(sprintf("i.%s", cols)) ][]
}

# cleanup loop vars
rm(d, cols)
```

This should work for more general cases with...

- more key cols (in `kc`) and
- more tables with non-overlapping col names (in `DTs`).

---

If you want the key cols as the key in the result, the code simplifies a little:

```
# make main table with key col(s)
DT = setkey(unique(rbindlist(lapply(DTs, `[`, j = ..kc))))

# get non-key cols
for (d in DTs){
  cols = setdiff(names(d), kc)
  DT[d, (cols) := mget(sprintf("i.%s", cols)) ][]
}
```

Comment: I was almost going down the same trail (check which keys are in both, then do the 'inner outer' join on both and then append half NA blocks for the unmatched). This seems to work but I prefer the solution given by Prem because it is shorter and more 'inside' the data.table package...

Comment: @FabianWerner Ok. Btw, if you are sure that `left` has all keys, you can just do a vanilla left join (if I'm using that term correctly) to add by reference there: `left[right, data_right := i.data_right ]`